# Extract specific data after using split() on a time series with multiple values per time stamp

Tags: r, split, time-series

I have a timeseries containing multiple values per day.These are multiple input values from one source. Some days in the intervall are missing(no input values). So I started with identifying the unique days and then grouping the different values for each day using split(). Now I want to create a frame/matrix with varying row lengths. where the column length is the same as the length of the dates vector below. In order to acces the values I have to write tu$`2015-02-16`. How can I build that matrix? I am new to R so my knowledge isn't that good. Also I would appriciate any tips on how to add a zero value in the rows for the missing days.

```
d <- unique(dates)
tu <- split(timeseries, dates)

tu[1]
$`2015-02-16`
      values        dates
1     129839.0 2015-02-16
2      40000.0 2015-02-16
3      79839.0 2015-02-16
4      97528.0 2015-02-16
5      75416.5 2015-02-16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a different sample of data, and using the `dplyr` and `tidyr` package:

```
set.seed(314)
df <- data.frame(values = rnorm(100),
                 dates = sample(as.Date('2017-01-01')+1:20,100,replace = T))


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

res <- df %>% group_by(dates) %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  spread(dates, values,fill = 0)
```

results in:

```
> res$'2017-01-02'
[1] -0.83870302  0.26933081  1.69739790  1.18466071 -0.07604657  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
```

or with R base you can use:

```
spl <- split(df, df$dates)

row.n <- max(sapply(spl, nrow))

do.call(cbind,lapply(spl, function(x) c(x$values, rep(0, row.n-nrow(x)))))
```

Comment: Thanks @Wietze314! The R base solution is exactly what I was looking to do!